# I'd like to store aeson's Value type using acid

Tags: haskell, acid, aeson

I'd like to store aeson Values usig acid-store. I've taken a minimal acid implementation and tried to naively switch the types over to Value. These are my calls to deriveSafeCopy:

```
$(deriveSafeCopy 0 'base ''Object)
$(deriveSafeCopy 0 'base ''Array)
$(deriveSafeCopy 0 'base ''Number)
$(deriveSafeCopy 0 'base ''Value)
$(deriveSafeCopy 0 'base ''JSONState)
$(deriveSafeCopy 0 'base ''JSONStateStore)
```

JSONState and JSONStateStore are my own types. I get this error:

```
Can't derive SafeCopy instance for: (Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Object,TyConI (TySynD Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Object [] (AppT (AppT (ConT Data.HashMap.Base.HashMap) (ConT Data.Text.Internal.Text)) (ConT Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Value))))
```

Comment: Thanks - do you think I should remove the update from the question? I'm not sure about SO etiquette.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evidently you've reached a limit of what the `deriveSafeCopy` Template Haskell function can do for you.

You can solve the issue by providing the instances manually. [SafeCopy API](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/safecopy/0.8.1/doc/html/Data-SafeCopy.html) contains comprehensive docs on how to do that. For additional examples you can check out [how the default instances are declared](http://hub.darcs.net/Lemmih/safecopy/browse/src/Data/SafeCopy/Instances.hs).

Comment: Thank you Nikita, that's what I expected. I think I just needed to hear it from someone. Thanks for a push in the right direction.

Comment: I added my solution above.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my implementation for those who are still interested:

```
-- | ACID

$(deriveSafeCopy 0 'base ''JSONStateStore)
$(deriveSafeCopy 0 'base ''JSONState)
$(deriveSafeCopy 0 'base ''Value)
$(deriveSafeCopy 0 'base ''Number)

-- | An instance of SafeCopy for the Array Value.
instance SafeCopy a => SafeCopy (V.Vector a) where
    getCopy = contain $ fmap V.fromList safeGet 
    putCopy = putCopy . V.toList

-- | An instance of SafeCopy for the Object Value.
instance (SafeCopy a, Eq a, Hashable a, SafeCopy b) => SafeCopy (H.HashMap a b) where
    getCopy = contain $ fmap H.fromList safeGet 
    putCopy = contain . safePut . H.toList
```

Comment: The putCopy definitions are incorrect and will not work as expected. They will compile however, so this is quite dangerous. The correct putCopy implementations should be (contain . safePut . toList)